# Changing the position of plotly modebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to specify the position of plotly modebar in plotly.js . I want to shift the vertical position of the modebar. Following this (https://community.plotly.com/t/its-possible-to-set-modebar-position-above-the-graph/31995) post, I tried to specify the modebar settings in the layout field. But the position of modebar is not shifting in the y-direction when y is changed in the following lines of code i.e. `layout` argument of plotly.

Code:

```js
var layout = {
    sliders: [slider],

    //for changing the 2D view
    xaxis: {
        visible: false,
        showgrid: false,
    },
    yaxis: {
        visible: false,
        showgrid: false,
    },
    zaxis: {
        visible: false,
        showgrid: false,
    },

    modebar: {
        bgcolor: 'red', // Customize the background color of the modebar
        orientation: 'h', // Set the modebar orientation to vertical
        x: 0.05, // Adjust the horizontal position of the modebar (0-1 range)
        y: 0.5, // Adjust the vertical position of the modebar (0-1 range)
        buttons: [
          {
            name: 'Custom Button',
            icon: {
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              path: 'M50 0 L100 100 L0 100 Z', // Define the path for the button icon
              ascent: 0.9,
              descent: 0.1,
            },
          }
        ]
    }
};

Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout, {displayModeBar: true});
```

Alternatively,  I also tried to specify the CSS in the style tag of HTML.

```
#network.modebar {
    position: absolute;
    {#top: 75% !important;#}
    left: 25%;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    {#bottom: 25%;#}
}
```

This shifts the modebar in the x direction. But I am not able to shift along y-direction.

Suggestions on how to change the y-coordinate of the modebar will be really helpful.

Comment: The modebar doesn't have x|y attributes. You should be able to do that with css though, using the selector `.modebar-container` it should be fine (or prepend an identifier if you have more than one plot on the page, but in this case you must have a space between the container id and the actual selector). If you target the inner element .modebar it works too but only with absolute values (ie. in px, you won't be able to apply a percentage).

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks a lot. Defining `#network .modebar { top: 150px;  left: 200px;
   }` in CSS works great!