# How to rearrange modebar in plotly bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

How can I move the modebar of plotly bar charts to the bottom instead of top?

[image]

I´m also interested, how to disable it. (But more important for me is the movement)

I have no idea, don´t find any config items in `px.bar` and `update_layout`. 
There´s only an option for orientation `".update_layout(modebar_orientation="v")"` for example.

Comment: I don't think you can change the placement of the modebar in plotly python. in plotly.js, it is possible (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76656003/changing-the-position-of-plotly-modebar))